# How to fix the Vue Router guard rerouting problem?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, jwt, vue-router

I'm setting up a laravel, vue project and i am using **JWT auth** for the user **authentication**. I am trying to protect the Routes with Vue Router and it is getting token from the local storage and giving access to the authentic user to specific route, but once on another route if i click on any other route or refresh the page it redirects me on the `"/login"` page again. The token remains same all the time but it is considering the token as the user is not authentic. Please help as i am new to laravel and vue

I have tried using meta info but that didn't work as well. Moreover, i have tried deleting the token from local storage and created it again but nothing works for me.

**routes.js file**

```
    export const routes = [
    {
        path: '/', component: Home, name: 'home'
    },
    {
        path: '/dashboard', component: Dashboard, name: 'dashboard', meta:{requiresAuth: true}
    },
    {
        path: '/login', component: Login, name: 'login'
    }
];
```

**App.js file**

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import { routes } from './routes.js';

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  console.log(to)
  if (to.meta.requiresAuth) {
    const authUser = JSON.stringify(window.localStorage.getItem('usertoken'))
    if(authUser && authUser.accessToken){
      console.log("here")
      next();
    }else{
      next({name: 'login'});
    }
  }
  next();
  });

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router
});
```

I expect the output to be like when the user is authentic and the `router.beforeEach` method finds a token, the user can get to any route until the token gets deleted or changed. Moreover, the user should not be taken to `'/login'` everytime a `<router-link>` is clicked or page is refreshed.

Comment: Should you not be using `JSON.parse` instead of `JSON.stringify` in your `beforeEach` function?

Comment: @DelenaMalan I used `JSON.parse` before but with that it gave me `SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"` and it didn't run.

Comment: Sounds like you aren't storing your `usertoken` value correctly. Could you add the code where you store the token to your question?

Comment: @DelenaMalan I was just trying to solve it and it is working now...the problem was with the line `if(authUser && authUser.accessToken)` . I added `authUser.accessToken` as a condition which was not fulfilled, so it was redirecting on every click. I removed that condition and just left with `if(authUser)` and now it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to solve it and it is **solved**...the problem was with the line `if(authUser && authUser.accessToken)` . I added `authUser.accessToken` as a condition which was not fulfilled, so it was redirecting on every click. I removed that condition and just left with `if(authUser)` and now it is working perfectly. Also I have added `JSON.stringify` to change my object to text and then authenticate with `JSON.parse` by passing a variable.

My final code looks like:-

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  console.log(to)
  if (to.meta.requiresAuth) {
    var usertoken = JSON.stringify(window.localStorage.getItem('usertoken'))
    const authUser = JSON.parse(usertoken)
    if(authUser){
      console.log("here")
      next();
    }else{
      next({name: 'login'});
    }
  }
  next();
  });
```